# Proof of Tonelli's lower semiconticontinuity with a regular functional

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, weak-convergence

I have the following statement:

Consider $F(u) = \int_a^b f(x,u(x))\, dx$ with $f \in C^1(a,b)$ and such that $f$ is convex in $u$. Also we further assume $f \ge 0$ for any $x,u$.
If $u_n \to u$ weakly in $L^1$, then $\liminf_{n \to +\infty} F(u_n) \ge F(u)$.

It resambles [Tonelli's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%27s_theorem_(functional_analysis)), my try to give a proof is the following:

Since $f$ is convex in $u$ we have that
$$F(u_n) = \int_a^b f(x,u_n(x))\, dx 
          \ge \int_a^b f(x,u(x)) \, dx + \int_a^b f_u(x,u(x))(u_n - u) \, dx$$
Noting that $f_u$ is continous over a compact, follows that $f_u \in L^\infty$.
Therefore $\int_a^b f_u(x,u(x))(u_n - u)) \, dx \to 0$ since $u_n \to u$ weakly in $L^1$. Therefore by taking $\liminf$ on both sides we conclude the proof.

Is the proof correct? There are some missing details that I should take care of?

Comment: Even if $f :[a,b]\times \mathbb R$ is cont.  differentiable, then it is not clear that $f_u \in L^\infty$: $(u_n)$ is converging in $L^1$ not in $L^\infty$.

Comment: You can prove the weak continuity proving (a) convexity and (b) continuity of $F$, since continuity and convexity imply weak lower semicontinuity.